# SQL Datetime difference in days

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, datetime, datediff

I am trying to find how many days are between two dates.  I have been attempting to use this:

```
SET Days_Outstanding = DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT(datetime, LS_CHG_DTE_EQP, 1), CONVERT(datetime, Report_Date, 1))
```

However, this is not returning the number in days.  It's returning a datetime in years that have nothing to do with my data set.

I'm not sure where the problem is, still fairly new to SQL.  Also, I have Days_Outstanding defined as an int, could that be the problem?  Thanks!

### EDIT

Thanks everyone!  Not sure what happened, I changed a few things to what you suggested and it wound up working when I went back to what I had originally.  Not sure what happened.  Thanks thought!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DATEDIFF` returns integer

However, the number of days could be plain wrong depending on the values/datatype of `LS_CHG_DTE_EQP/Report_Date` and `locale`

Also, `DATEDIFF` works on day boundaries not 24 hour periods. So `23:56` to `00:02` is one day.

Otherwise, please add example input and output.

Answer (score 3):

Example

```
select DATEDIFF(dd,'20100101',getdate())
```

will return 227 today

so in your case assuming LS_CHG_DTE_EQP and Report_Date are both datetime columns

```
SET @Days_Outstanding = DATEDIFF(day, LS_CHG_DTE_EQP, Report_Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just

```
SET Days_Outstanding = CONVERT(datetime, LS_CHG_DTE_EQP, 1) - CONVERT(datetime, Report_Date, 1))
```